# In C#, given an intptr to a window handle, how do I measure this window handle's true height using scrollinfo

Tags: c#, scroll, intptr

I have a sub-window within a scroll window in a separate application. I am attempting to use a C# console application to inspect that scroll-window's true height (not its on screen height, but the height in pixels of how many pixels can be scrolled). I know using the existing user32.dll libs I can ask for a scroll info but that gives me details about the scrollbar itself, the scrollbar's height and position, but it doesn't give me the total pixels that the scrollbar would scroll through.

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
private static extern bool GetScrollInfo(IntPtr hwnd, int fnBar, ref ScrollInfo lpsi);
```

Is there a way I can use the scrollinfo returned by the above method to derive the actual pixels of the scrollable area?

```
public struct ScrollInfo
{
    public uint cbSize;
    public uint fMask;
    public int nMin;
    public int nMax;
    public uint nPage;
    public int nPos;
    public int nTrackPos;
}
```

Comment: maybe you want `GetClientRect` *"retrieves the coordinates of a window's client area. The client coordinates specify the upper-left and lower-right corners of the client area. Because client coordinates are relative to the upper-left corner of a window's client area, the coordinates of the upper-left corner are (0,0)."*

Comment: The problem with getting the Rect is its only on-screen pixels.